# :: jQuery :: Append element as case-sensitive and non-standard html elements

Tags: jquery

I have different custom shapes, when I click on button, one image should be appended to its parent SVG file with same shape (masking image inside svg shape).

Everything working as expected except below glitches

- Trying wrap my svg path inside `<clipPath>`, but getting `<clippath>`
- trying to add `<image>` tag, but it is automatically converting as `<img>` tag.

How can I append elements as case sensitive and exact element.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs1Lzcjn/)**

**HTML**

```
<svg id="cusotmShape" version="1.1" style="width:100px;height:100px;" stroke="off" set-as-background="no" class="custom-shape cs-shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 135.8 130.8" xml:space="preserve">
    <path rp-cp-id="rp-shape-02" class="cs-element-layer" fill="#000000" style="stroke:transparent;stroke-width:0px;" d="M100.4,128.4l-26.8-13.5c-2.9-1.5-6.4-1.4-9.3,0.2l-26.2,14.4c-7.3,4-15.9-2.1-14.7-10.3l4.5-29.6 c0.5-3.2-0.6-6.5-3-8.8L3.1,60.3c-6-5.7-2.9-15.8,5.2-17.1l29.6-4.8c3.2-0.5,6-2.6,7.4-5.6L58.1,5.7C61.6-1.8,72.2-2,76,5.4L89.7,32 c1.5,2.9,4.4,4.9,7.6,5.3l29.7,3.8c8.2,1,11.7,11,5.8,16.9l-20.9,21.3c-2.3,2.3-3.3,5.7-2.7,8.9l5.6,29.5 C116.3,125.7,107.8,132.1,100.4,128.4z"></path>
</svg>

<div><button type="button" id="insertImage">Insert Image</button></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#insertImage', function (e) {
var _custom_shape_svg = jQuery('svg#cusotmShape');
var _custom_shape_svg_id = jQuery('svg#cusotmShape path').attr('rp-cp-id')
  _custom_shape_svg.wrapInner('<clipPath id="' + _custom_shape_svg_id +'"></clipPath>');
  _custom_shape_svg.append('<image clip-path="url(#' + _custom_shape_svg_id +')" xlink:href="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg"  src="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg" alt="Image" height="100" width="100" class="svg__image" />');
});
```

**What am I getting:**

```
<svg id="cusotmShape" version="1.1" style="width:100px;height:100px;" stroke="off" set-as-background="no" class="custom-shape cs-shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 135.8 130.8" xml:space="preserve">
    <clippath id="rp-shape-02">
        <path rp-cp-id="rp-shape-02" class="cs-element-layer" fill="#000000" style="stroke:transparent;stroke-width:0px;" d="M100.4,128.4l-26.8-13.5c-2.9-1.5-6.4-1.4-9.3,0.2l-26.2,14.4c-7.3,4-15.9-2.1-14.7-10.3l4.5-29.6 c0.5-3.2-0.6-6.5-3-8.8L3.1,60.3c-6-5.7-2.9-15.8,5.2-17.1l29.6-4.8c3.2-0.5,6-2.6,7.4-5.6L58.1,5.7C61.6-1.8,72.2-2,76,5.4L89.7,32 c1.5,2.9,4.4,4.9,7.6,5.3l29.7,3.8c8.2,1,11.7,11,5.8,16.9l-20.9,21.3c-2.3,2.3-3.3,5.7-2.7,8.9l5.6,29.5 C116.3,125.7,107.8,132.1,100.4,128.4z"></path>
    </clippath>
    <img clip-path="url(#rp-shape-02)" xlink:href="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg" src="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg" alt="Image" height="100" width="100" class="svg__image">
</svg>
```

**Expected**

```
<svg id="cusotmShape" version="1.1" style="width:100px;height:100px;" stroke="off" set-as-background="no" class="custom-shape cs-shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 135.8 130.8" xml:space="preserve">
    <clipPath id="rp-shape-02">
        <path rp-cp-id="rp-shape-02" class="cs-element-layer" fill="#000000" style="stroke:transparent;stroke-width:0px;" d="M100.4,128.4l-26.8-13.5c-2.9-1.5-6.4-1.4-9.3,0.2l-26.2,14.4c-7.3,4-15.9-2.1-14.7-10.3l4.5-29.6 c0.5-3.2-0.6-6.5-3-8.8L3.1,60.3c-6-5.7-2.9-15.8,5.2-17.1l29.6-4.8c3.2-0.5,6-2.6,7.4-5.6L58.1,5.7C61.6-1.8,72.2-2,76,5.4L89.7,32 c1.5,2.9,4.4,4.9,7.6,5.3l29.7,3.8c8.2,1,11.7,11,5.8,16.9l-20.9,21.3c-2.3,2.3-3.3,5.7-2.7,8.9l5.6,29.5 C116.3,125.7,107.8,132.1,100.4,128.4z"></path>
    </clipPath>
    <image clip-path="url(#rp-shape-02)" xlink:href="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg" src="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg" alt="Image" height="100" width="100" class="svg__image">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a markup string into `$`, it's parsed as HTML using the browser's `innerHTML` property on a `<div>` (or other suitable container for special cases like `<tr>`). `innerHTML` can't parse SVG or other non-HTML content.

`innerHTML` is not available on SVGElement—it is a property of HTMLElement only. jQuery doesn't give you easy access to the namespaced methods needed to create SVG elements. Really jQuery isn't designed for use with SVG at all and many operations may fail.

So maybe this leads to your problem: `<clipPath>` to `<clippath>` and `<image>` to `<img>`

To be able to create `svg` tags, use [document.createElementNS(namespaceURI, qualifiedName[, options])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS)

For example:

```
const namespaceURI = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
const clipPath = document.createElementNS(namespaceURI, 'clipPath')
clipPath.id = 'clippy';
    
const image = document.createElementNS(namespaceURI, 'image')
image.id = 'image-id'
```

Finally, you can try like this to resolve the problem:

```js
const _svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const customShape = document.getElementById('customShape');

const svg = customShape.appendChild(document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'image'));
svg.setAttribute('x', '0');
svg.setAttribute('y', '0');
svg.setAttribute('width', '100%');
svg.setAttribute('height', '100%');
svg.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#clippy)');
svg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg');

// create clipPath
const clipPath = customShape.appendChild(document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'clipPath'));
clipPath.id = 'clippy';

$('#insertImage').click(function () {
    const path = clipPath.appendChild(document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'path'));
    path.setAttribute('d', 'M100.4,128.4l-26.8-13.5c-2.9-1.5-6.4-1.4-9.3,0.2l-26.2,14.4c-7.3,4-15.9-2.1-14.7-10.3l4.5-29.6 c0.5-3.2-0.6-6.5-3-8.8L3.1,60.3c-6-5.7-2.9-15.8,5.2-17.1l29.6-4.8c3.2-0.5,6-2.6,7.4-5.6L58.1,5.7C61.6-1.8,72.2-2,76,5.4L89.7,32 c1.5,2.9,4.4,4.9,7.6,5.3l29.7,3.8c8.2,1,11.7,11,5.8,16.9l-20.9,21.3c-2.3,2.3-3.3,5.7-2.7,8.9l5.6,29.5 C116.3,125.7,107.8,132.1,100.4,128.4z');
})
```

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    background: #000080;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

svg#customShape {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

svg#customShape > path {
    stroke:transparent;
    stroke-width:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="customShape" stroke="off"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 135.8 130.8" xml:space="preserve">

     <path class="cs-element-layer" fill="#000000"
      d="M100.4,128.4l-26.8-13.5c-2.9-1.5-6.4-1.4-9.3,0.2l-26.2,14.4c-7.3,4-15.9-2.1-14.7-10.3l4.5-29.6 c0.5-3.2-0.6-6.5-3-8.8L3.1,60.3c-6-5.7-2.9-15.8,5.2-17.1l29.6-4.8c3.2-0.5,6-2.6,7.4-5.6L58.1,5.7C61.6-1.8,72.2-2,76,5.4L89.7,32 c1.5,2.9,4.4,4.9,7.6,5.3l29.7,3.8c8.2,1,11.7,11,5.8,16.9l-20.9,21.3c-2.3,2.3-3.3,5.7-2.7,8.9l5.6,29.5 C116.3,125.7,107.8,132.1,100.4,128.4z">

     </path>
</svg>

<div>
    <button type="button" id="insertImage">Insert Image</button>
</div>
```

Comment: **@Lam Tran Duc**, Excellent... This is what exactly I want... Thanks for the answer